# Algoritmo de encriptamiento que hace el output mas pequeño que el input

Tags: encriptación, hash, criptografía

Hay algún algoritmo de encriptamiento que puede hacer que el output sea mas pequeño que el input y que aparte se pueda recuperar el texto original?

No busco algo como MD5 que haga que el contenido no se pueda recuperar.

Comment: ¿Qué lenguaje de programación ocupas?

Comment: @CristianAndrésHiguita javascript

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar algo así, capturar el dato que deseas encriptar en una variable la cual vas a inyectar o enviar,

Luego creas un ciclo y le das la cantidad a la cadena que deseas armar, sería como algo así.

```
var text = '*';
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++;){
  text += '*';
}
```

la variable ext sería la que mandarías como output

Comment: No le veo caso, solamente estas declarando dos variables, una en texto plano y la otra son solo un ponton de "*"